# Change mysql query to show tasks only on specified days

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working on a transport planner and to show the tasks by the selected date I'm using the following mysql query:

```sql
    SELECT *
    FROM planner
    WHERE '$date' >= date
    AND '$date' <= valid_till
    AND (frequency = 'daily'
    OR (frequency = 'once' AND date('$date') = date)
    OR (frequency = 'weekly' AND 0 = (abs(datediff('$date', date)) % 7))
    OR (frequency = 'two-weekly' AND 0 = (abs(datediff('$date', date)) % 14))
    OR (frequency = 'monthly'
    AND ceil(dayofmonth('$date')/7) = ceil(dayofmonth(date)/7)
    AND dayofweek('$date') = dayofweek(date)))
    AND dayofweek('$date') <> '1'
    AND dayofweek('$date') <> '7'
```

Now I have some tasks that need to be shown only on monday, wednesday and thursday by example.
I thought I create a new column to my planner table: only_on_days (varchar) which I fill like: '2, 4, 5' where 2 stands for monday, 4 for wednesday an 5 for thursday.

Can someone help me to change my query to add this functionality?
Or maybe there are much better ideas?

**EDIT**

I've created a new table: **planner_days** which looks like (example):

```
id --- planner_id --- day
1          12          2
2          12          3
3          12          4
4          12          5
5          12          6
6          13          3
7          13          5
```

I tried to make a join query like you said @eugen-rieck.

```
SELECT planner.*, planner_days.*
FROM planner
LEFT JOIN planner_days
ON planner.planner_id = planner_days.planner_id
WHERE '$date' >= date
AND '$date' <= valid_till
AND (frequency = 'daily' AND dayofweek('$date') = planner_days.day
OR (frequency = 'once' AND date('$date') = date)
OR (frequency = 'weekly' AND 0 = (abs(datediff('$date', date)) % 7))
OR (frequency = 'two-weekly' AND 0 = (abs(datediff('$date', date)) % 14))
OR (frequency = 'monthly'
AND ceil(dayofmonth('$date')/7) = ceil(dayofmonth(date)/7)
AND dayofweek('$date') = dayofweek(date)))
AND dayofweek('$date') <> '1'
AND dayofweek('$date') <> '7'
```

This works but now tasks that have to be showed every day are shown multiple times..
Does someone have a solution for this?

Comment: ... `OR (frequency = 'mon_wed_thur ' AND ( dayofweek('$date') <> '2' OR dayofweek('$date') <> '4' OR dayofweek('$date') <> '5')` ...

Comment: This is a possibility, but I have also tasks that have the be shown only on monday and friday, and tasks have to be shown only on tuesday, thursday and friday by example.

Answer (score 4):

**NEVER EVER** store more than one information in a single field, if you want to **access them seperately**. Putting a CSV list into a field is a recipe for desaster.

The canonical way is to have a jointable with the `taskid` and the days to show them, then resolve your `AND dayofweek('$date') <> '1' AND dayofweek('$date') <> '7'` into a Join

Comment: Sounds like a good idea, but can you help me a little more please? I'm still not very good at this and working with joins.. @eugen-rieck

Comment: And when I'm using the taskid from some task, then what about the tasks that have to be shown every day?

Comment: For every-day tasks, you create 7 (or 5 for workdays) rows in the jointable, alternatively you could allow another value than 1-7 (maybe 0) to mean every day, but I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: Can you please take a look at my new query and help me to get the other tasks diplayed with another frequency then daily? @eugen-rieck

Comment: Add `GROUP BY planner.planner_id` to the end of the query

Comment: There's only one thing, when using this query I can't select the planner_id from tasks with an other frequency then daily, because that kind of tasks do not exists in the planner_days table. Is there a way to fix this (little) problem? @eugen-rieck